# The check keyword not working in sql management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, check-constraints

I have two tables `tblA` and `tblB`. And a constraint called `tblA_tblB_FK` is created between these tables. I wanted to update both columns in tables chained with `tblA_tblB_FK` constraint. While reading different posts I  thought the best way is to disable the constraint for a moment and enable again after the update. For that reason I executed these queries:

```
alter table tblA NOCHECK CONSTRAINT tblA_tblB_FK
```

After this step I did the update and till now everything was OK, but then I tried to enable again the constraint, so I executed this query:

```
ALTER TABLE tblA CHECK CONSTRAINT tblA_tblB_FK
```

and it says command successfully completed. But when I try to make update again it doesn't stop me from doing that, meaning there is a problem with the enabling process. I tried to execute another query:

```
ALTER TABLE tblA WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT tblA_tblB_FK
```

and it doesn't allow me complaining there is `tblA_tblB_Fk` constraint active. I don't understand why it allows me to make an update, while it doesn't allow me to execute this command?

I am using SQL Server 2005. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you insert and update specification for the foreign key in management studio under Table>Table_name>Keys folder. It might be set to "Cascade".

Comment: are you updating the parent table or dependent table?

Comment: try restarting sql server.